# move a generated file to directory using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, file, base64

I'm using angularjs and I genereated an image file based64.

given a problem of security policy, I can't save the image data to database,

so I created a code that transform an image based64 to blob file.
But I want to move it to a target directory in the project.

```
  var blob = new Blob([data.img], {type: 'image/png'});
        var file = new File([blob], 'test.png');
```

so right now, I want to move the image file (file)  to a directory image in the project.

I ask if there are any option in angularjs that give me the possibility to move the file to the directory?

Thanks you for helps

Comment: just like [sharing something between the controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers), you can use a service/factory to store your files in (just inject it into your directive and get the image from it)

Comment: I want to save the file in the directory